# Tinkerpop Gremlin console not working

Tags: orientdb, gremlin, tinkerpop

I have installed Tinkerpop 3.0 M4 and Gremlin console, both 3.0 M4.
I am not able to do neither the following:

1) to load a database already existing, 
2) to create the classic DB.

The Database is working fine in Java thrugh Tinkerpop 3, just Gremlin console isn't.
While opening the DB I have the same identical issue with Gremlin 2.6 from OrientDB install, so it is not due to version incompatibility between OrientDB 2.0M2 and Grails 2.6 or 3.0M4 (nor M5).
I can't figure out what is the problem.

**1) This is the command I give in Gremlin to open the Database:**

```
g = new OrientGraph("local:/opt/orientdb/databases/dbname", "user", "password");
```

**This is the exception I get:**

```
groovysh_evaluate: 3: unable to resolve class OrintGraph
@ line 3, column 5.
g = new OrintGraph("local:/opt/orientdb/databases/circletask");
   ^

1 error
Display stack trace? [yN] y
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
groovysh_evaluate: 3: unable to resolve class OrintGraph
 @ line 3, column 5.
   g = new OrintGraph("local:/opt/orientdb/databases/circletask");
   ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:309)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:938)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:585)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:534)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:286)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:259)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:674)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:686)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:722)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Interpreter.evaluate(Interpreter.groovy:62)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.execute(Groovysh.groovy:159)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:121)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.work(ShellRunner.groovy:93)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor25.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:123)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.run(ShellRunner.groovy:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at com.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.<init>(Console.groovy:99)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:636)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at com.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.main(Console.groovy:230)
```

**2) This is the command to create the Tutorial DB:**

```
gremlin> Graph g = TinkerFactory.createClassic();
```

**This is the exception I get:**

```
No such property: TinkerFactory for class: groovysh_evaluate

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: TinkerFactory for class: groovysh_evaluate
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:231)
    at groovysh_evaluate.run(groovysh_evaluate:3)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Interpreter.evaluate(Interpreter.groovy:68)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.execute(Groovysh.groovy:159)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:121)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.work(ShellRunner.groovy:93)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor25.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:123)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.run(ShellRunner.groovy:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at com.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.<init>(Console.groovy:99)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:636)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at com.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.main(Console.groovy:230)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found that plugin where not active by default as expected:

```
gremlin> :plugin list
         ==>tinkerpop.server
         ==>tinkerpop.gephi
         ==>tinkerpop.sugar
         ==>tinkerpop.utilities
         ==>tinkerpop.tinkergraph
```

that solved the problem:

```
:plugin use tinkerpop.server
:plugin use tinkerpop.tinkergraph
:plugin use tinkerpop.utilities
```

Answer (score 1):

The Error says:

```
groovysh_evaluate: 3: unable to resolve class OrintGraph
 @ line 3, column 5.
   g = new OrintGraph("local:/opt/orientdb/databases/circletask");
```

So seems you misspelled the class OrientGraph in OrintGraph? Try using OrientGraph.

Answer (score 1):

There is no OrientDB implementation for TinkerPop3 at this time.